# ValueError Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-8-873e6e28bcfb> in <module>()

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to build a model to identify handwritten digits from images. I have written a code and now I want to view the predictions of my model but I got stuck and it shows me an error like:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helper'.

Below is the code;

```
%matplotlib inline
import helper

images,labels=next(iter(trainloader))
img=images[0].view(1,784)

with torch.no_grad():
    logits=model.forward(img)

ps=F.softmax(logits,dim=1)
helper.view_classify(img.view(1,28,28),ps)
```

Comment: Check if helper is installed in system or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going through a Udacity course, it's a module they wrote. You can simply drop in this code,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def view_classify(img, ps, version="MNIST"):
    ''' Function for viewing an image and it's predicted classes.
    '''
    ps = ps.data.numpy().squeeze()

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,9), ncols=2)
    ax1.imshow(img.resize_(1, 28, 28).numpy().squeeze())
    ax1.axis('off')
    ax2.barh(np.arange(10), ps)
    ax2.set_aspect(0.1)
    ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(10))
    if version == "MNIST":
        ax2.set_yticklabels(np.arange(10))
    elif version == "Fashion":
        ax2.set_yticklabels(['T-shirt/top',
                            'Trouser',
                            'Pullover',
                            'Dress',
                            'Coat',
                            'Sandal',
                            'Shirt',
                            'Sneaker',
                            'Bag',
                            'Ankle Boot'], size='small');
    ax2.set_title('Class Probability')
    ax2.set_xlim(0, 1.1)

    plt.tight_layout()
```

and call the function directly.

Here's [another variant](https://github.com/udacity/DL_PyTorch/blob/master/helper.py). Not sure which is the most current or compatible with what you need.